# SSDT exclude fill factor from table definition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, schema-compare, sqlpackage

SSDT has an option to ignore fill factor (`IgnoreFillFactor`). But what it actually does is: *it doesn't flag object as changed if there are only fill factor changes*. If there are some additional changes fill factor will be published together with those.

The actual issue comes when someone is using schema compare to compare development database with database project, then it brings fill factor together with other changes (`IgnoreFillFactor` doesn't work here as well) to database project and this gets applied to the production via publish. I know that it is possible to edit the database project and exclude fill factor manually, but this is not a very practical workaround.

Is there a way to completely exclude fill factor from table definitions using SSDT?